# What is the usage of Maven pom.xml - <tag> element inside of <scm> when you are using git

Tags: git, maven, maven-scm

We are using maven and git together for a Java project.  In `<scm>` section, `<tag>` is automatically added by release plugin.

For example,

```
  <scm>
          <connection>scm:git:http://myserver:7990/scm/project/test.git</connection>
          <tag>releaes-tag</tag>
  </scm>
```

What does `<tag>` represent here?

I believe the normal convention is `<tag>HEAD</tag>.`

When we were using subversion, maven never used `<tag></tag>`

What is the meaning of `<tag></tag>`?

I searched google and maven documentation but I cannot find any information on it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `<tag>` element is used by `release:prepare` to specify the tag that was created for this release (implemented as [MRELEASE-723](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-723)). Outside of a release it is essentially a placeholder, and `HEAD` is an appropriate value.

> When we were using subversion, maven never used `<tag></tag>`

As `MRELEASE-723` explains:

> when I invoke release:prepare with
>   a URL like:
>   `https://example.test/svn/REPO/myproject/branches/release` it will be
>   replaced by `https://example.test/svn/REPO/myproject/tags/myproject-1.0`
>   which is fine because now you know which revision to checkout for
>   building the release.

The `<scm>` element for a release build should contain enough information to check out the tag that was created for this release.

Subversion allows the tag to be included in the connection URL. Neither Git nor Mercurial allow this, so the `<tag>` element is used instead.

Comment: But on a branch (snapshot version of the artifact) I can simply remove the `<tag>HEAD</tag>` right? And have it just set automatically on the maven release for the release tag. Or does it always add it back to HEAD after a release?

Comment: Perhaps I'm just thick but I still don't understand the need for *automated* adding of `<tag>` in the `<scm>` section. I tend to remove it when I see it but it keeps popping back.

Comment: So, the value of `<tag>` is uniquely chosen when running the `release:prepare` goal (the user is prompted for it). And afterwards the goal is sticking such value into the `pom.xml` under `<scm>/<tag>` just to store this information?

Comment: The reference for the [technical maven project descriptor](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/maven-model/maven.html#class_scm) (i.e. the technical specification of the POM file) states that the default value for the `<tag>` element is indeed `HEAD`, so that's what is assumed when you don't specify the tag (just like `jar` is the default for the `<packaging>` element).